# Search tuples between two string of dates

Tags: python, performance, tuples

I want to list the values inside a tuples between two dates(string), My data look like this:

```
[(1, 'ch-01-07-1', '2021-07-01', '262', 'okinama', 'OR15G9431', 'Dhenkanal', 'FULAPADA', '67', '450', '34', '395151.0', 'Not Yet'),
 (3, 'ch-01-07-3', '2021-07-02', '262', 'okinama', 'OR 21 7911', 'Dhenkanal', 'FULAPADA', '67', '450', '34', '395151.0', 'Not Yet'),
 (4, 'ch-01-07-4', '2021-07-01', '262', 'okinama', 'OR 21 7911', 'Dhenkanal', 'DIGHI', '67', '450', '34', '299743.0', 'Not Yet'),
 (5, 'ch-01-07-5', '2021-07-03', '262', 'okinama', 'OR 21 7911', 'Dhenkanal', 'CUTTACK', '67', '450', '34', '384163.0', 'Not Yet'),
 (6, 'ch-01-07-6', '2021-07-04', '262', 'okinama', 'OR 21 7911', 'Dhenkanal', 'BARSINGHA (BARAMBA)', '67', '450', '34', '356425.0', 'Not Yet'),
 (7, 'ch-18-07-1', '2021-07-12', '256', 'ultra tech', 'OR 21 7911', 'Dhenkanal', 'DERA', '52', '63', '21', '340672.0', 'Not Yet'),
 (8, 'ch-18-07-2', '2021-07-11', '457', 'ultra tech', 'OR15G9431', 'Dhenkanal', 'DHENKANAL TOWN AREA (M.PAT, COLLEGE BYEPASS)', '45', '5677', '66', '88082.0', 'Not Yet'),
 (9, 'ch-18-07-3', '2021-07-15', '545', 'okinama', 'OR 21 7911', 'Dhenkanal', 'FULAPADA', '67', '66', '55', '395514.0', 'Not Yet'),
 (10, 'ch-18-07-4', '2021-07-09', '545', 'ultra tech', 'OR 21 7911', 'Dhenkanal', 'FULAPADA', '67', '66', '55', '395514.0', 'Not Yet'),
 (12, 'ch-01-07-2', '2021-07-08', '123', 'ultra tech', 'OR 21 7911', 'Dhenkanal', 'DHUBALAPALA (TELKOI)', '23', '23', '12', '287534.0', 'Not Yet'),
 (17, 'ch-2021-07-1', '2021-07-12', '565', 'ultra tech', 'OR 21 7911', 'Dhenkanal', 'DHENKANAL TOWN AREA (UPTO MAHAVEER BAZAR) ', '32', '33', '22', '61289.0', 'Not Yet'),
 (19, 'ch-2021-07-2022', '2021-07-18', '741', 'okinama', 'OR 21 7911', 'Dhenkanal', 'FULAPADA', '21', '22', '22', '123961.0', 'Not Yet'),
 (20, 'ch-2021-07-2023', '2021-07-19', '693', 'ultra tech', 'od062598', 'Dhenkanal', 'DUDURKOTE', '78', '78', '78', '352014.0', 'Not Yet'),
 (21, 'ch-2021-07-2024', '2021-07-20', '123', 'okinama', 'OR 21 7911', 'Dhenkanal', 'CUTTACK', '10', '100', '100', '57210.0', 'Not Yet')]
```

for example i want to search dates between "2021-07-03" to "2021-07-15", then as a result i expect the rows of 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 17 to list in my console and further if with column number of [5] where value is equal to "ultra tech" then to list the rows of 7, 8, 10, 12, 17.

Comment: Not sure what you're looking for, a simple `for` is as far as you can go with Python, you need to scan all the tuples. 500k lines does not seem like too much. If you need more "performance" then you'll need to change programming language. Another good option would be to use a DBMS to hold and query your data.

Comment: I am looking for code to search rows that are in between 2 given dates. Do i need to convert the all the date string to `datetime` format or the string format will do the work

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the date to integer this way.

```
cr_date = "2021-07-03"
cr_date = list(map(int, cr_date.split('-')))
start_date = 10000 * cr_date[0] + 100 * cr_date[1] + cr_date[2]
```

Then for query:

```
find_value = 'ultra tech'


for t in data:
    cr_date = list(map(int, str(list(t)[2]).split('-')))
    find_date = to_int(cr_date)
    if end_date >= find_date >= start_date:
        search_result.append(t)
        if find_value in t:
            adv_search.append(t)
```

Comment: shows attribute error: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'` in `cr_date = list(map(int, str(list(t)[2]).split('-')))` line

Comment: It runs on my  machine without this error. If you look at the code, `tuple` converted to `list`, then we took the index value from `list` and converted to `string`. after then `split()` used here. It may vary for python version not sure.

Answer (score 0):

from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date
d1 =  date(2021,7,3)
d2 = date(2021,7,15)
for b in A:
if(b[4]=="ultra tech"):
c = datetime.strptime(b[2], "%Y-%m-%d").date()
print(c)
if (d1 < c < d2):
print(b)